# How to create a Datepicker FormHelper in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4 application I have this helper method that creates a `text_field` with a `hidden_field` just underneath it:

```
module FormatHelper

  def datepicker_field(f, options = {})
    text_field_tag(nil, format_date(f.object.date || Date.today), options) +
    f.hidden_field(:date)
  end

end
```

In my forms I use it like this:

```
<%= datepicker_field(f) %>
```

I would prefer to do this instead, though:

```
<%= f.datepicker_field(:date) %>
```

How can this be done in Rails?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own Formbuilder class and use it in a particular form:

Taken from the [Formbuilder docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) :

```
class MyFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def div_radio_button(method, tag_value, options = {})
    @template.content_tag(:div,
      @template.radio_button(
        @object_name, method, tag_value, objectify_options(options)
      )
    )
  end
end
```

and then your form should be something like:

```
<%= form_for @person, :builder => MyFormBuilder do |f| %>
  I am a child: <%= f.div_radio_button(:admin, "child") %>
  I am an adult: <%= f.div_radio_button(:admin, "adult") %>
<% end -%>
```